Git pre-commit hook that searches for text in staged hunks
I want to prevent committing files with a certain string, e.g.:
// TODO foo bar baz

So I use a git pre-commit hook:
#!/bin/sh

EXTENSIONS='\.(cs|cshtml|csproj|css|js|scss|sh|ts|xml|yml|md)?$'
FORBIDDEN='TODO'

git diff --cached --name-only | \
  sed -n -E "/$EXTENSIONS/p" | \
  GREP_COLORS='4;5;37;41' xargs grep --color --with-filename -n "$FORBIDDEN" \
  && echo 'ERROR: Found forbidden texts; remove them then retry' && exit 1 \
  || exit 0

That works. It has one flaw though.
The grep searches for the forbidden text in the entire file, rather than just the staged hunks. So if a file has hunks which I stage, and one hunk with the forbidden text (which I do not stage), then it will cancel the commit.
Is it possible to search for the pattern in the staged hunks only, rather than the entire file?
(I'd like for the script to work in dash.)

Just two ideas: You could first stash changes, which could help already. Apart from that, you can use git diff --staged foo.sh to look at only the staged changes in foo.sh.

Isn't it simply ! git diff --cached | grep "$FORBIDDEN"? (exclamation to invert exit code: 1 for found, 0 for not found)?

@UlrichEckhardt Thanks Ulrich. Using the stash is a little tricky but that would probably work, interesting idea! The --staged switch I believe is a synonym for --cached which is what I used and gives the same result.

@phd The script is based on the one I linked to - I didn't consider there may be an easier way without the sed. Thanks for the idea!

@phd Your idea was good - this simpler script works as expected: FORBIDDEN='TODO'; git diff --staged | grep --quiet "$FORBIDDEN" && echo exit 1 || exit 0. However, it works for all hunks from all files, not just code files listed in $EXTENSIONS above. It's a good start to the solution, thanks for putting me on the right track!

git diff --cached -- "*.cs" "*.cshtml" "*.csproj" "*.css" "*.js" "*.scss" "*.sh" "*.ts" "*.xml" "*.yml" "*.md" should diff only files with selected extensions. Quotes to prevent shell to expand patterns in the current directory — Git interprets them in the entire tree.

@phd Thanks that worked! If you drop that into an answer I'll close.

You actually only want to forbid that new $FORBIDDEN text is introduced, but you certainly don't want to forbid that someone removes such text or that it is just an innocent bystander (in context lines or file names). Make it ... | grep --quiet "^\+.*$FORBIDDEN".

Funny thing I just noticed: I wrote --staged above, which is exactly the right flag, because it looks at the staged changes. However, and I verified that in my shell history, I have never used that flag myself! I always use --cached, which is IMO badly named and should be frowned upon, because there is no kind of cache involved here!

@UlrichEckhardt Agreed. I only learnt that those two are synonyms because of this issue... I always used "cached", which is poorly named. I doubt I'll remember the details of this issue in a month, but I won't forget about "staged" :-)

I think the hook could be as simple as
#!/bin/sh
! git diff --cached -- "*.cs" "*.cshtml" "*.csproj" "*.css" "*.js" "*.scss" "*.sh" "*.ts" "*.xml" "*.yml" "*.md" |
    grep --quiet "TODO"

Exclamation sign to invert exit code: 1 for found, 0 for not found. Quotes over * to prevent shell to expand patterns in the current directory and pass the patterns to Git — Git interprets them in the entire tree.
